# How to configure source maps when using Jest within Visual Studio Code debugger

Tags: debugging, react-native, babeljs, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I am writing an app using react native and I want to be able to test my code using the jest framework and use the visual studio code editor debugger to set breakpoints. The problem I am currently having is no matter how I run the debugger, whether it is through spawning a new instance or attaching it, I can't seem to get the source maps to work from babel. I have tried a variation of configurations within the .babelrc file but none seem to work.

VScode version - 1.6.0(latest)

My directory structure resembles this

```
-package.json
-node_modules
-.babelrc
-dist
-app
 -myModule.js
 -test
   -myModule.spec.js
```

then in my .babelrc I have the following

```
{
    "presets" : ["react-native"],
    "sourceMaps" : true,
    "outDir" : "./dist"
}
```

I have tried setting the `sourceMaps` prop to both `true` and `inline` and both did not work with current `launch.json` configuration.

Here is my `launch.json` for running the Jest tester

```
{

            "name" : "Launch via jest",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program" : "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [
                "--runInBand"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--harmony"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "outDir" : "${workspaceRoot}/dist"
}
```

Both `--harmony` and `--runInBand` are necessary to get the debugger working properly since Jest will spawn a child process which conflicts with the ports.

I also have additional Jest configuration within my package.json

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  }
```

Now whenever I run the debugger, It runs and it stops at the babel output's breakpoints instead of the original source which doesn't help much. I should also mention that the test itself is compiled by babel which I am unsure if it matters.

Any pointers or different configurations are all welcomed.

Comment: did you find a solution in the meantime ?

Answer (score 6):

The .babelrc option is `sourceMap` singular. `{ "sourceMap" : "inline" }` works for me.

Comment: Works for me too.

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to get VS Code proper source map and breakpoint placement in source files instead of transpiled to work with Jest + Babel by:

1. Making sure Babel generates sourceMaps, this is by setting sourceMap to inline in the `babel` section of my `package.json` (you might need to do it in your `.babelrc.json` instead).
2. In my VS Code `launch.json` file I replaced debugger from `node` to `pwa-node`. This allowed me to specify the `resolveSourceMapLocations` property and indicate to VS Code that the source files are in my workspace directory. I think this is needed because of Jest building the files in its own cache.

My full `launch.json` config:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
            "args": [
                "--no-cache",
                "--config",
                "${workspaceRoot}/jest.config.json",
                "--runInBand",
                "--detectOpenHandles"
            ],
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "test"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "smartStep": true, 
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**",
                "node_modules/**"
            ],
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using VS Code 1.53, Jest 25.5.4

Answer (score 0):

What is your jest configuration? I was seeing weird transpiled output related to coverage until I added the following config value:

`"testRegex": "src/.*\\.test\\.js$"`