# How to debug unconverted source code correctly in react18 jest unit test?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

Environment:react18 source code, win10 , node v16.13.1

I'm using jest tests inside the source code to explore the react18 source code,but jest use babel to convert source code, when i debug jest unit test,it will jump to babel's converted code,it is hard to read,
So I want to ask is there any way to debug on the source code,not the converted code?
for Example:
[image]
when i debug it,it will  be converted
[image]

Even in some places,It's almost unreadable:
[image]

i want to debug unconverted source code correctly in react18 jest unit test.

here is my vscode lanuch.json config:

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest Current File",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
      "args": [
        "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "--config",
        "./scripts/jest/config.source.js",
        "--runInBand"
      ],
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "windows": {
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure source maps when using Jest within Visual Studio Code debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003070/how-to-configure-source-maps-when-using-jest-within-visual-studio-code-debugger)

Comment: thanks,but that doesn't seem to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

i found in 'preprocessor.js' file , it contain babel configuration

[image]

so,we just add global item process.env.JEST_ENABLE_SOURCE_MAPS : inline.

Comment: Please do not use code images copy/past your code in the post with a good formatting